# JNA, Native DLL, Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, jna

I need to load the DLL library into Web Service Project. In stand alone application use JNA library and the load goes well. 
Error code: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a definition of `native` method. Thus because the exception is thrown.